# list to dictionary with multiple values per key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, type-conversion

I have a Python list which holds pairs of key/value :

```
list = [ {'A': {'value': '2h25m'}, 'B': {'value': '2:45 AM'}, 
          'C': {'value': 'LAX'}, 'D': {'value': '+0100'}} ]
```

I want to convert the list into a dictionary like this:

```
d = {'A': '2h25m', 'B': '2:45 AM', 'C': 'LAX', 'D':'+0100'}
```

Thks

Answer (score 3):

```
lst = [ {'A': {'value': '2h25m'}, 'B': {'value': '2:45 AM'}, 'C': {'value': 'LAX'}, 'D': {'value': '+0100'}} ]
my_dict = dict([(k, v['value']) for k, v in lst[0].items()])
```

First of all, don't use `list` as a variable name as it shadows the built-in `list()` function. Furthermore, as you can see, I've used a list comprehension to built a list with (key, value) tuples which can then be passed to the `dict()` function to create the desired dictionary.

As mgilson points out, you can also use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension:

```
lst = [ {'A': {'value': '2h25m'}, 'B': {'value': '2:45 AM'}, 'C': {'value': 'LAX'}, 'D': {'value': '+0100'}} ]
my_dict = dict((k, v['value']) for k, v in lst[0].items())
```

Comment: You can change the list comprehension into a generator expression if you' like.  The difference is probably minimal in this case, but it seems like good practice none the less.

Comment: In Python 3 you could use a dict comprehension: `my_dict = {k: v['value'] for k, v in lst[0].items()}`

Comment: Actually you can do `my_dict = {k: v['value'] for k, v in lst[0].items()}` in python 2.7 and above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [dict comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) in later versions of Python:

```
In [30]: lst = [ {'A': {'value': '2h25m'}, 'B': {'value': '2:45 AM'}, 
    ...:           'C': {'value': 'LAX'}, 'D': {'value': '+0100'}} ]

In [31]: {k: v['value'] for k, v in lst[0].items()}
Out[31]: {'A': '2h25m', 'B': '2:45 AM', 'C': 'LAX', 'D': '+0100'}
```